# How is Python's decimal (and other precise decimal libraries) implemented and why are they slower than built in floating point calculations?

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal

I've been reading the [floating point guide](https://floating-point-gui.de/formats/exact/) to try to clarify some points about floating point numbers and I assume Python's decimal library is an implementation of "Limited-Precision Decimal" mentioned on the linked page.

It mentions that "Limited-Precision Decimal" is "Basically the same as a IEEE 754 binary floating-point, except that the exponent is interpreted as base 10. As a result, there are no unexpected rounding errors. Also, this kind of format is relatively compact and fast, but usually slower than binary formats."

Is Python [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) implemented the same way? If all else is equal in the representation besides the exponent being interpreted differently, why is it slower and why isn't this representation always preferred over the IEEE 754 implementation? Finally, why does using the exponent as base 10 prevent unexpected rounding errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It mentions that "Limited-Precision Decimal" [...] Is Python decimal implemented the same way?

No, internally Python's Decimal uses a base-10 exponent, along with an arbitrarily large integer. Since the size of the integer is unlimited, the potential precision is unlimited too.

> why is [Python's Decimal] slower

There are a few reasons for this. First, adding two Decimal values of different exponents requires multiplying by ten, and multiplying by ten is more expensive than multiplying by two on a computer which uses binary. Second, doing an exact calculation requires more digits of precision than doing an approximate calculation. Third, IEEE754 floating point has hardware acceleration because it's such a common operation.

> why isn't this representation always preferred over the IEEE 754 implementation?

Speed is a feature, and not all calculations benefit from being done exactly. The use of inexact calculations is more widespread than you might think. For example, Excel [uses floating-point numbers internally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result). Yet, it has hundreds of millions of users, so evidently you can get pretty far with only floating point.

> Finally, why does using the exponent as base 10 prevent unexpected rounding errors?

The key word in that sentence is "unexpected." You wouldn't be surprised to learn that a base 10 number system can't represent the number 1/3 without rounding it. We understand and are okay with not being able to represent 1/3, 1/7, and 1/9 perfectly accurately. But people are much less accepting of computer systems which can't represent 1/5 accurately.

If you tried to represent 0.2 in binary, you'd get 0.0011(0011), with the 0011 part repeating forever. A floating point number doesn't have an infinite number of bits, so it rounds off everything after 53 bits (assuming double precision) and approximates it.

This is not to say that Decimal is perfectly accurate. There are lots of situations that force rounding. For example, if you took the square root of two, that's an irrational number, and can't be represented as an exact decimal.

Example:

```py
>>> Decimal(2).sqrt()
Decimal('1.414213562373095048801688724')
>>> Decimal(2).sqrt() ** 2
Decimal('1.999999999999999999999999999')
```

Decimal is a way of doing math that agrees with the answer you'd get by doing it with pencil and paper. For this, it trades off speed and memory use.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer! A few follow up questions if you don't mind:
- So if the exponent is in base 10, we are now interpreting the exponent as 10^1, 10^5, etc. Are we also interpreting the significand/mantissa any differently than before or is it still 2^-1, 2^-2, and so on?

Comment: "First, adding two Decimal values of different exponents requires multiplying by ten, and multiplying by ten is more expensive than multiplying by two on a computer which uses binary." can you clarify this point? Not totally getting why multiplication is involved here in the first place although I assume it's to make the exponents equal to allow the numbers to be added.

Comment: - “Second, doing an exact calculation requires more digits of precision than doing an approximate calculation.” - I would think this only comes into play if you actually specify a precision greater than that afforded by the standard floating point numbers?

Comment: “If you tried to represent 0.2 in binary, you'd get 0.0011(0011), with the 0011 part repeating forever. A floating point number doesn't have an infinite number of bits, so it rounds off everything after 53 bits (assuming double precision) and approximates it.” Any chance you have a concrete example showing actual bits of how this would be represented with Decimal such that this issue is avoided? I think that’s what I’m having trouble wrapping my head around since I haven’t found any tools like https://float.exposed/ that help you with actual examples. Thanks!!

Comment: "Are we also interpreting the significand/mantissa any differently than before or is it still 2^-1, 2^-2, and so on?" The mantissa is interpreted as an integer times the exponent. The formula is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/_pydecimal.py#L517).

Comment: "Not totally getting why multiplication is involved [...] I assume it's to make the exponents equal to allow the numbers to be added" Yes, that's why. "I would think this only comes into play if you actually specify a precision greater than that afforded by the standard floating point numbers?" Yes, but if you specify the same level of precision, reasons 1 and 3 still apply.

Comment: "Any chance you have a concrete example showing actual bits of how this would be represented with Decimal" To represent 0.2 with a Decimal object, you would have an integer with a value of 2 and an exponent with a value of -1. I don't know of a calculator to show a bitwise representation of it like a float.